# Configure Base Url in Axios with React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-typescript, react-query

how can I set up my baseURL in axios with React Typescript?

I tried doing `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'myurl.com';`

But, it's not working. In the network tab, it says that the promise is pending.

Any idea how can I achieve it?

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'myurl.com';


const useCampaign = (token: string, campaignID: string) =>
  useQuery(
    'campaign',
    () =>
      axios
        .get(`/api/campaigns?lgp-webview-token=${token}`, {
          headers: { 'X-Campaign-ID': campaignID }
        })
        .then((res) => res.data),
    {
      retry: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false
    }
  )

export default useCampaign
```

Comment: Here is a little [guide](https://dev.to/iamsourabhh/how-i-use-axios-in-react-30hi) to use the Axios in react application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make a file called axios.js and setup the following and then import that file in your required component as `import axios from "./axios";` and then use this local axios in your code

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({

  baseURL: "myurl.com"
});

export default instance;
```

Comment: inspect element and check the network tab if the request is going through

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't an Axios issue. It was related to CORS. Thanks, your code is working 