# How to fetch json data by axios in react with proxy?

Tags: reactjs, api, proxy, axios, next.js

I created an app with next.js. In one of its page, wrote this code:

```
../pages/index.js

   1   │ import axios from 'axios';
   2   │
   3   │ const Page = ({ data }) => {
   4   │   return (
   5   │     <div>
   6   │       <div>Welcome to Next.js!</div>
   7   │       {data.map((d) => (
   8   │         <p key={d.id}>{d.title}</p>
   9   │       ))}
  10   │     </div>
  11   │   );
  12   │ };
  13   │
  14   │ export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  15   │   const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts');
  16   │   console.log(data);
  17   │   return {
  18   │     props: {
  19   │       data,
  20   │     },
  21   │   };
  22   │ };
  23   │
  24   │ export default Page
```

Some packages like this, just prepared `next`, `react` and `axios`.

```
   1   │ {
   2   │   "name": "app",
   3   │   "version": "1.0.0",
   4   │   "description": "",
   5   │   "main": "index.js",
   6   │   "scripts": {
   7   │     "dev": "next dev",
   8   │     "build": "next build",
   9   │     "start": "next start"
  10   │   },
  11   │   "author": "",
  12   │   "license": "",
  13   │   "dependencies": {
  14   │     "axios": "^0.21.1",
  15   │     "next": "^10.2.2",
  16   │     "react": "^17.0.2",
  17   │     "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  18   │   }
  19   │ }
```

When start the app and access it from browser, I got this error:

```
Server Error
Error: Request failed with status code 504

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Sometimes also got a 403 error.

From the log of the app, I found some information like

```
app_1  |         responseUrl:
app_1  |          'http://proxy.company.com:12302/http://localhost:4000/posts',
...
app_1  |   isAxiosError: true,
app_1  |   toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
```

Why it added prefix `http://proxy.company.com:12302/`? How to set proxy with axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL provided to axios HTTP functions is appended to base URL from context.

You can override the base URL by creating an axios instance and using that for your HTTP calls.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000'
});

instance.get('/posts').then(
  res => console.log(res, res.data),
  err => console.log(err)
)
```

More info in the official [README](https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance)

[Related issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63912645/13099243)

Comment: How to return `res` data in this way?

Comment: You can just replace `console.log(res, res.data)` with `res.data`. A javascript arrow function without curly braces returns the expression after the arrow.

You need to also await the async axios call to assign the result into a variable like in the question example.